# How load / save blobs from / to Azure blob storage?

Tags: codefluent

My model has an entity with a property of type 'blob'. At the moment a database column of type "varbinary(max)" is generated. However, I want to load/save my blob from/to Azure blob storage. What property type do I have to use in my model? What configuration do I need in my web.config file? Do you have an example project?

Answer (score 0):

In the **CodeFluent.Runtime.Azure** dll you will find the **AzureBinaryLargeObject** call and its related configuration **AzureBinaryServicesEntityConfiguration**.
See [Azure BLOB](https://www.softfluent.com/documentation/BOM_BLOB_WindowsAzureBlobStorage.html)
This should do the treak. 
However it relies on the Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.dll not included in newest version of Azure SDK. You can get it in this specific [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/1.7.0)